# On which thread is a CancellationToken's registered callback invoked when it is requested from another thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task, cancellation-token, cancellationtokensource

Suppose I have a task running in another thread, with a cancellation callback (from `Register`) registered during that thread's execution.

Then the owner of the `CancellationTokenSource` invokes `Cancel` from the main thread. Where/when is the cancellation callback invoked? In the main thread where the cancellation was requested, or in the background thread where it was registered?

Answer (score 0):

The callback registered with `CancellationToken.Register` is executed on the thread that calls `CancellationTokenSource.Cancel()`. So, if you invoke Cancel from the main thread, the callback will be executed on the main thread. It will not be executed on the background thread where the callback was registered.

An example:

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
var token = cts.Token;

Task.Run(() =>
{
    token.Register(() =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Callback executed on thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
    });
    
    Console.WriteLine($"Background thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
    // Simulate some work
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
});

Console.WriteLine($"Main thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
Thread.Sleep(500); // Give the background task some time to start and register the callback
cts.Cancel();
```

and the output is:

```
Main thread 1
Background thread 20
Callback executed on thread 1
```

Hope this helps.